# Strategy Condition (2nd bar close above/below condition)

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am literally brand new to pine script and have stumbled my way to this point but I really am stumped. Thanks in advance for any direction.

I am trying to create a simple strategy around EMA/SMA. I am looking to force the strategy to not take the long or short exit unless exitcondition(long&short)1 has 2 consecutive closes below/above the condition defined. The strategy is working as intended otherwise but I was hoping I would be able to add this variable to test different setups.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © bubblyApple52984

//@version=5
strategy("EMA strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
ema_input1 = input.int(1, "Fast")
ema_input2 = input.int(2, "Slow")
sma_input3 = input.int(3, "SuperSlow")

plot(ta.ema(close, ema_input1),"fast",color.green)
plot (ta.ema(close, ema_input2),"slow",color.white)
plot (ta.sma(close, sma_input3), "superslow",color.red)

shortCondition1 = close < ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
shortCondition2 = ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close, ema_input1), ta.ema(close, ema_input2))
shortCondition3 = ta.ema(close,ema_input1) < ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
shortCondition4 = ta.ema(close,ema_input2) < ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
exitConditionShort1 = close >= ta.ema(close, ema_input2)
//exitConditionShort2 = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close, ema_input1), ta.ema(close, ema_input2))
inTradeShort = strategy.position_size < 0
if (shortCondition1 and shortCondition2 and  shortCondition3 and shortCondition4)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
if (exitConditionShort1 and inTradeShort)
    strategy.close(id="My Short Entry Id", comment="CloseShort")
    
longCondition1 = close > ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
longCondition2 = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close, ema_input1), ta.ema(close, ema_input2))
longCondition3 = ta.ema(close,ema_input1) > ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
longCondition4 = ta.ema(close,ema_input2) > ta.sma(close, sma_input3)
exitConditionlong1 = close <= ta.ema(close, ema_input2)
//exitConditionlong2 = ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close, ema_input1), ta.ema(close, ema_input2))
inTradelong = strategy.position_size > 0
if (longCondition1 and longCondition2 and longCondition3 and longCondition4)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
if (exitConditionlong1 and inTradelong)
    strategy.close(id="My Long Entry Id", comment="CloseLong")
```

This is what I have and it works but it completes the "strategy.close" off the 1st candle close above/below the ema_input2. I need help making this strategy close the position based on the 2nd consectutive bar close above/below the ema_input2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the [previous value](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%5B%5D) of exitConditionShort1, and the current value

Something like that

```
if (exitConditionShort1 and exitConditionShort1[1] and inTradeShort)
    strategy.close(id="My Short Entry Id", comment="CloseShort")
```